# Do I need to generate new token to see new smart sheet data

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am using smart sheet API to pull data from smart sheet. it is working fine. Recently new smart sheet was added. Access was given to user for this new smart sheet but when I call smart sheet API it returns "not found" response.

All other existing sheets works.
Do I need to generate new token every time we add new sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to generate a new token, though it's possible that the token you have doesn't have the correct user permissions for the new sheet (although I think this would generate a 403 error instead of a 404). Assuming the permissions are correct, you *might* run into a latency problem (under 1 minute) while the new sheet is mirrored into all databases. Please try again to see if the problem resolves itself. 
If that doesn't work, please reply here.

Comment: I tried again today and getting same error. Error code "1006" and message "Not found"

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's happening exactly without seeing a log. Can you send a log to devrel@smartsheet.com?

Comment: I am testing this call using POSTMAN tool. Where can I find smartsheet log?